# How can I create a computed array in Vue and then render it using v-if all while using v-model on the computed array?

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

I've been trying to create a computed array which I then render using v-if. But it also needs to work with v-model. The reason it needs v-model is because it's part of a draggable list using vuedraggable.

Currently I get the following error `Computed property "list" was assigned to but it has no setter.`

The following code is my drag.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <draggable
      v-model="list"
      v-bind="dragOptions"
      class="bigger-area"
      @start="isDragging=true"
      @end="isDragging=false"
    >
      <transition-group name="flip-list" type="transition">
        <li
          v-for="text in list"
          :key="text"
          id="list1"
          class="drag-item flex flex-justify-betweeen"
        >{{ text }}</li>
      </transition-group>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  name: "Drag",
  data() {
    return {
      test: [],
      lists: [
        {
          title: "0-6 months",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Lifting Head",
            "Rolling",
            "Sitting (with support)"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "6-12 months",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Crawling on stomach",
            "Sitting (without support)",
            "Stands with support and walks holding on",
            "Rolls a ball"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "12-18 months",
          correctlyOrderedList: ["Crawling", "Walks alone"]
        },
        {
          title: "18 months – 2 years",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Walks smoothly and turns corners",
            "Walks upstairs with support",
            "Begins running"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "2-3 years",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Walks upstairs without support",
            "Runs safely",
            "Catches using body and arms"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "3-4 years",
          correctlyOrderedList: ["Kicks a ball forwards", "Can hop on one foot"]
        },
        {
          title: "4-5 years",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Catches using only their hands",
            "Can skip following a demonstration"
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  components: {
    draggable
  },
  methods: {
    fullArrayMethod() {
      //Puts all statements into single array
      let i;
      let v;
      let fullArrayInOrder = [];
      for (i = 0; i < this.lists.length; i++) {
        for (v = 0; v < this.lists[i].correctlyOrderedList.length; v++) {
          fullArrayInOrder.push(this.lists[i].correctlyOrderedList[v]);
        }
      }
      return fullArrayInOrder;
    },
    disorderedArrayMethod() {
      //Randomizes array
      let fullArrayInOrder = this.fullArrayMethod();
      var copy = [],
        n = fullArrayInOrder.length,
        i;
      // While there remain elements to shuffle…
      while (n) {
        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * fullArrayInOrder.length);

        // If not already shuffled, move it to the new array.
        if (i in fullArrayInOrder) {
          copy.push(fullArrayInOrder[i]);
          delete fullArrayInOrder[i];
          n--;
        }
      }
      return copy;
    },
    chunk(array, size) {
      const chunked_arr = [];
      let index = 0;
      while (index < array.length) {
        chunked_arr.push(array.slice(index, size + index));
        index += size;
      }
      return chunked_arr;
    },
    splitArrayFinalProduct() {
      let disorderedArray = this.disorderedArrayMethod();
      let finalArray = this.chunk(disorderedArray, 3);
      return finalArray;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    dragOptions() {
      return {
        animation: 0,
        group: "shared",
        disabled: false,
        ghostClass: "ghost"
      };
    },
    list() {
      return this.disorderedArrayMethod();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

***Context***: I'm trying to create an application which consolidates multiple arrays into one. Randomises the array. The user can then put it back in order and then see if they got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may find it useful this is what worked for me. I can't explain the in's and outs of why it works so hopefully somebody smarter than me can elaborate.

To get the computed array variable to work with v-model and v-for I used `map()` as shown below:

```
let completeListOfStatements = this.lists.map(
d => d.correctlyOrderedList
);
```

My understanding of `map()` is it returns an array.

Then in the v-model I set it to the array that is within the object. This is the same one that I used `map()` on. This can be seen below.

```
<draggable
   v-model="lists.correctlyOrderedList"
   v-bind="dragOptions"
   class="list-group"
   @start="isDragging=true"
   @end="isDragging=false"
>
```

For comparisons to the code in my question here's all the code from the component:

```
<template>
  <div class="draggable-list-container">
    <div
      class="draggable-list-inner-container"
      v-for="(statement, index) in splitCompleteListOfStatements"
      :key="index"
    >
      <h1>{{ lists[index].title }}</h1>
      <draggable
        v-model="lists.correctlyOrderedList"
        v-bind="dragOptions"
        class="list-group"
        @start="isDragging=true"
        @end="isDragging=false"
      >
        <transition-group name="flip-list" type="transition">
          <li
            v-for="(statement, index) in statement"
            :key="index + 'index'"
            class="drag-item flex flex-justify-betweeen"
          >{{ statement }}</li>
        </transition-group>
      </draggable>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-button-container">
      <button class="btn" @click="revealAnswers">Reveal answers</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  name: "Drag",
  data() {
    return {
      lists: [
        {
          title: "0-6 months",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Lifting Head",
            "Rolling",
            "Sitting (with support)"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "6-12 months",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Crawling on stomach",
            "Sitting (without support)",
            "Stands with support and walks holding on",
            "Rolls a ball"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "12-18 months",
          correctlyOrderedList: ["Crawling", "Walks alone"]
        },
        {
          title: "18 months – 2 years",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Walks smoothly and turns corners",
            "Walks upstairs with support",
            "Begins running"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "2-3 years",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Walks upstairs without support",
            "Runs safely",
            "Catches using body and arms"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "3-4 years",
          correctlyOrderedList: ["Kicks a ball forwards", "Can hop on one foot"]
        },
        {
          title: "4-5 years",
          correctlyOrderedList: [
            "Catches using only their hands",
            "Can skip following a demonstration"
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  components: {
    draggable
  },
  methods: {
    disorderedArrayMethod(value) {
      //Randomizes array
      let fullArrayInOrder = value;
      var copy = [],
        n = fullArrayInOrder.length,
        i;
      // While there remain elements to shuffle…
      while (n) {
        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * fullArrayInOrder.length);

        // If not already shuffled, move it to the new array.
        if (i in fullArrayInOrder) {
          copy.push(fullArrayInOrder[i]);
          delete fullArrayInOrder[i];
          n--;
        }
      }
      return copy;
    },
    revealAnswers() {this.splitCompleteListOfStatements[0].push("Hello")}
  },
  computed: {
    dragOptions() {
      return {
        animation: 0,
        group: "shared",
        disabled: false,
        ghostClass: "ghost"
      };
    },
    splitCompleteListOfStatements() {
      let completeListOfStatements = this.lists.map(
        //Maps out full array (Basically loops through gathers the arrays and creates an array from them)
        d => d.correctlyOrderedList
      );
      completeListOfStatements = completeListOfStatements.reduce(function(
        //The map returns an array as the following [[a,b], [], []] etc. So this turns it into [a,b,c,d]
        a,
        b
      ) {
        return a.concat(b);
      }, []);
      completeListOfStatements = this.disorderedArrayMethod(
        completeListOfStatements
      ); //This sends it to a method that jumbles the array

      var temp = [];
      var preVal = 0;
      var nextVal = 3;
      for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        temp.push(completeListOfStatements.slice(preVal, nextVal));
        preVal = nextVal;
        nextVal = nextVal + 3;
      }
      return temp;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.title {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.submit-button-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.btn {
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
}
.draggable-list-container {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.list-group {
  min-height: 80px;
}
.drag-item {
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: move;
}
.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.no-move {
  transition: transform 0s;
}
.ghost {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #c8ebfb;
}
.list-group-item {
  cursor: move;
}
</style>
```